# How to check all active netem rules?

Tags: linux, networking, traffic-shaping, tc

I have been adding rules/settings (not sure what the correct terminology is here) with `tc`/`netem`, such as `tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 25ms`, and have been removing them after use.

However, now I would like to check which rules/settings are still active. Is there a command to view or check all active `netem` rules? I think the equivalent `iptables` command is something like `iptables -L`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command `tc qdisc` (or `tc q`) will show all active queueing disciplines, including any instances of `netem`. For example, after running the command `tc qdisc add dev eth0 root netem delay 25ms`, the output of `tc q` is:

```
qdisc netem 8005: dev eth0 root refcnt 2 limit 1000 delay 25.0ms
```

The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tc.8.html) for `tc` describes more options for displaying qdisc information.